# How can i add CardView In androidX

Tags: androidx

I add this line to my dependencies after many search to find out, how can add cardview in android x

implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

but after sync i gave this error

ERROR: Failed to resolve: cardview

please Help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGNaN.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow (SO). Here at SO we are a community trying to help each other. Please have a look at the "How do I ask a good question" (stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to better frame your question. Please do not post a screenshot of your code. Instead, have a look at the "Minimal, Reproducible Example" section (stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Hi and welcome! It would also help if you could post some more detailed error messages you have encountered.